Practices we can have to check if a python script Failed or is Successfull
Can any one suggest a good practice we can follow to track a python script.
Eg : If a script runs ,:
I need the start_time , End_time and if whether the execution was successful or not (0 or 1).
I believe we need to develop another python script to track this case and import that file to whichever script we need tracking.
But not able to implement to track the status of the execution.
Please share if you have any other good ideas.

Just wrap in a bash script
#!/bin/bash
time python myscript.py
echo "Exit status: $?"

If $? is non-zero, then there was an error, otherwise it was a success.
When myscript.py contains the line raise ValueError I get:
ValueError

real    0m0.037s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
Exit status: 1

and when it contains print("Hello world!") I get:
Hello world!

real    0m0.041s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
Exit status: 0


Can you please suggest how I can incorporate in my .py file
